# not adding em tag in IE

Tags: jquery

Here is my code.

```
<ul class="children">
<li class="page_item page-item-378 page_item_has_children"><a href="http://zealousys.com.au/service/mobile/ios/">iOS</a><em>+</em>
<ul class="children">
    <li class="page_item page-item-382"><a href="http://zealousys.com.au/service/mobile/ios/iphone/">iPhone</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-384"><a href="http://zealousys.com.au/service/mobile/ios/ipad/">iPad</a></li>
</ul>
```

And Jquery for it

```
$this.find("li").each(function() {
    if($(this).find("ul").size() != 0) {
           $(this).find("a:first").after("<em>"+ opts.closedSign +"</em>");
        }
}
```

Working in all browser but not in IE9...  Here is link for working example [here](http://zealousys.com.au/service/mobile/)

IN IE this give message like Internet explorer restricted this web page form running script or ActiveX control.

When i allow blocked content it works fine.

Comment: :) use $(this)  on 1st line

Comment: close tags . Include );   on the last line

Comment: @PratikJoshi: please refrain from irresponsible edits. In the code you can see `var $this = $(this);`. This is common practice. Also this is a snippet only.  close tags are not relevant. if you want to see the code, read from line 27 from this js file. http://zealousys.com.au/wp-content/themes/zealous/js/multiple-accordion-1.js

Comment: i know , i thought He has not defined var $this and using.Then tell Him to provide proper jquery so that i can solve error. or i will continue telling there are Syntax errors .

Comment: here i jquery which i use http://jsfiddle.net/anjanasolanki/RkQwq/11/

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this)` on 1st line Its clearly error in my console in Chrome ,Firefox also

Comment: close tags . Include });   on the last line